# Link pixels of a rasterizer to a canvas of my JavaFX application

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, pixel

So basically I have this custom Rasterizer class which will be used to draw lines, rectangles etc but I can't seem to find a way to link it to my JavaFX application using a javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas.

Here's my current approach:

```
    Rasterizer2D.setRasterBuffer(new int[765 * 503], 765, 503);
    Rasterizer2D.setDrawRegion(25, 50, 25, 60);
    Rasterizer2D.drawRectangle(50, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    Rasterizer2D.drawLine(10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0, 765, 503, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), Rasterizer2D.graphicsPixels, 0, 765);
```

The canvas is still empty after executing this code and I have no idea why.

Yes, I am aware that you can draw figures using the  canvas.getGraphicsContext2D() but that's not what I want.

Am I forgetting something perhaps?

Comment: Have you verified that `Rasterizer2D` is doing what it's supposed to do? In other words, does `Rasterizer2D.graphicsPixels` contain the correct data?

Comment: Yes, the graphicsPixels array contains the right data as far as I know.